# Static method return class's shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following snippet, `MyClass` has a static method which returns its shared pointer. To make to code concise, we use the alias `MyClassPtr` for `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>`.

However, to accomplish this, we declare the class before declaring the shared pointer alias, which then follows the actual class declaration. It looks verbose.

Is there some way to reorganize the code so that

- keep the `MyClassPtr` alias (it is shared across the project)
- without "declaring" `MyClass` twice

code below:

```
class MyClass;
using MyClassPtr = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>;

class MyClass {
public:
    static MyClassPtr createMyClassInstance();

private:
/*Other members & methods*/
}
```

I'm OK with the current implementation. But I would like to seek experienced guy's advice if the code can be improved.

Comment: Related? Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern

Comment: There is nothing to do with the Singleton pattern here... No idea why it is a duplicate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there some way to reorganize the code so that
>
> (1)keep the MyClassPtr alias (it is shared across the project)
>
> (2) without "declaring" MyClass twice

You you accept to declare `MyClassPtr` twice, you can declare it inside the class and "export" it outside

```
#include <memory>

class MyClass
 {
   public:
      using MyClassPtr = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>;

      static MyClassPtr createMyClassInstance();

   private:
      /*Other members & methods*/
 };

using MyClassPtr = MyClass::MyClassPtr;


int main()
 {
   MyClassPtr  np { nullptr };
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is somewhat vague, as you ask how the code can be *simplified*, yet you fail to provide any real code, only the outline of a class definition. Instead, I try to answer the more sensible question of how to *improve* your code. I suggest

1. Avoid the alias `MyClassPtr`, it's not really necessary (it should not be used much if you use `auto`) but more importantly reduces verbosity and hence readability of the code, since it's not obvious from its name that `MyClassPtr` refers to a `shared_ptr`.

   If you insist on having a shorthand for the smart pointer, you can define this *after* the class definition, thus avoiding the forward declaration
2. Rename `MyClass::createMyClassInstance` to something more verbose, I suggest `MyClass::createSharedPtr` (no need to have `MyClass` in the function name again).
3. Don't forget the `;` after a class definition.

Thus,

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<MyClass> createSharedPtr();    
private:
    /* Other members & methods */
};

using MyClassSharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>;  // optional
```

IMHO, good code should be self-explanatory and hence not necessarily most concise/brief, though redundancies must be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, `createMyClassInstance` is just a random name I pick up to illustrate the method's purpose. I'm wondering is there any way to avoid declaring `MyClass` "twice".

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. You only define it once, but can declare it as often as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Make `Ptr` a member type:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>;
    static Ptr createMyClassInstance();

private:
/*Other members & method*/
};

// ...

MyClass::Ptr p = MyClass::createMyClassInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the return type with auto:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static auto createMyClassInstance();

private:
/*Other members & method*/
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/088a1b2702f777c8):

Comment: You might still want the `using` statement, just after the class.

Comment: Yes, other classes will use `MyClassPtr` for brevity. That's the whole point of `using` in this case.